# PDF creation is ok but retrieve from the database getting row space

Tags: php, html, database, pdf

I am using **HTML to PDF method** for PDF geneartion in PHP.I retrieved data from the database successfully.I am getting the **More Spaces** between the rows why??
Please advise me.
This is my code...

```
require('WriteHTML.php');
include('connection.php');
$result = pg_query($db,"SELECT dvn_cd, allotment_date,allotment_no,quantity FROM ddhs_receipt_entry ");

$pdf=new PDF_HTML();

$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 15);

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image('logo.png',18,13,33);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
$pdf->WriteHTML('<para><h1>Title</h1><br>');

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',7); 
$htmlTable='<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD>Name</TD>
<TD>Email</TD>
<TD>URl</TD>
<TD>Comment</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>';

$pdf->WriteHTML2("$htmlTable");
while($value = pg_fetch_array($result)) {

$htmlTable2='<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD>'.$value['dvn_cd'].'</TD>
<TD>'.$value['allotment_date'].'</TD>
<TD>'.$value['allotment_no'].'</TD>
<TD>'.$value['quantity'].'</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>';
$pdf->WriteHTML2("$htmlTable2");
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',6);

 }

 $pdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is actually outputting lots of separate tables, and you want a single one. Try moving `<TABLE>` outside the `while` loop:

```
$htmlTable = '<TABLE>
    <TR>
    <TD>Name</TD>
    <TD>Email</TD>
    <TD>URl</TD>
    <TD>Comment</TD>
    </TR>';    // The table is opened at the start of this block, and headers are output

while($value = pg_fetch_array($result)) {

    $htmlTable .= '<TR>
        <TD>'.$value['dvn_cd'].'</TD>
        <TD>'.$value['allotment_date'].'</TD>
        <TD>'.$value['allotment_no'].'</TD>
        <TD>'.$value['quantity'].'</TD>
        </TR>';    // Each row of your table is added to the string here

}

$htmlTable .= '</TABLE>';    // The table is closed here

$pdf->WriteHTML2("$htmlTable");    // The table is written here

$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: I used your code.but table not coming and rows not aligned properly

Comment: You're absolutely right. I've fixed the code so that it now outputs and writes the whole table as a single block of HTML.

Comment: Sorry jack..your coding is correct.I did mistake.now works perfect

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
while($value = pg_fetch_array($result)) {

$htmlTable2='<TR>
    <TD>'.$value['dvn_cd'].'</TD>
    <TD>'.$value['allotment_date'].'</TD>
    <TD>'.$value['allotment_no'].'</TD>
    <TD>'.$value['quantity'].'</TD>
    </TR>';
$pdf->WriteHTML2("$htmlTable2");
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',6);

 }
$htmlTable='</TABLE>';
```

Comment: I used your code.but table not coming and rows not aligned properly

Comment: If you want to modify the layout and alignment. Please use inline css. You have to repeat the rows inside the while loop.